# Application hang: interpret WinDbg commands' output

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, windbg, sos

My `.NET` application uses BlockingCollection to process data received from RabbitMQ. Sometimes on production it stops processing messages. I made dump using `procdump` util and tried to inspect the dump using `WinDbg`. `!threads` command shows me one thread with `LockCount=1`. `~*e!clrstack` command gave me this output for another thread:

```
Child SP       IP Call Site
0f3bf068 7760c8ac [GCFrame: 0f3bf068] 
0f3bf118 7760c8ac [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 0f3bf118] System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean, Int32, System.Object)
0f3bf1a4 70ac5fb7 System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(System.Object, Int32, Boolean)
0f3bf1b4 70ad76a7 System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.WaitUntilCountOrTimeout(Int32, UInt32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
0f3bf1d0 70ad75f0 System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
0f3bf230 703dc110 System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib]].TryAddWithNoTimeValidation(System.__Canon, Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken)
```

I tried to find more information about locks. `!locks` command gave me only this `Scanned 40 critical sections`. `!SyncBlock` shows this:

```
Index         SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread Info          SyncBlock Owner
-----------------------------
Total           1364
CCW             1
RCW             1
ComClassFactory 0
Free            713
```

What is`GCFrame`? What is `CCW` and `RCW`? I can't find it in documentation.

Also is it a way to find the thread which owns the lock?

Comment: Is your BlockingCollection bounded? That's the only reason I can think of that would explain a thread remaining stuck on TryAddWithNoTimeValidation

Comment: Also, `!syncblk` shows no owner for the lock because there's none. The thread is blocked on `Monitor.Wait`, which means that it's waiting for another thread to acquire the lock and call `Monitor.Pulse`. To me it seems that the BlockingCollection has reached its maximum capacity, therefore the thread is blocked waiting for someone to remove elements from the collection. What you need to investigate is what the consumer is doing